# Woocommerce: sorting variable product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How do I show variations sorted by quantity in stock? I can override or extend the WC_Product_Variable class, but this solution doesn't seem optimal. What other options are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`woocommerce_get_children`](https://wp-kama.com/hook/woocommerce_get_children) filter:

```
function wpse_filter_variations( $variations, $product, $false ) {
    // Do you sorting here

    return $variations;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_children', 'wpse_filter_variations', 10, 3 );
```